# PHP Write Permission - FC13

Tags: php, apache2, fedora, selinux

I have recently installed FC13 and am attempting to write a mechanism in my PHP code that caches gathered data into a specific directory (for our purposes here, let's call it /var/www/html/_php_resources/cache).

I copy my files over to the /var/www/html directory and then run `chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/*` and `chmod a+w /var/www/html/_php_resources/cache` on the new data.  For right now I am just using the global write permission for convenience.  I will tweak the permissions later.

When I attempt to use the `chmod` or `mkdir` PHP functions I wind up with:

> Warning: chmod(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/_include/php/CacheInit.php

or

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/_include/php/CacheInit.php

Now, when I disable SELinux everything works just fine.  The problem is that I would prefer **not** to disable SELinux and actually get the permissions set up correctly so that I can port it over to servers where someone does not have such explicit control.

As an example: my personal site host allows me to set read/write permissions on directories but will not allow for SELinux policy changes.

---

FYI:

- **uname -r** = 2.6.34.7-56.fc13
- **php -version ** = PHP 5.3.3
- **rpm -qa | grep httpd** = httpd-2.2.16-1.fc13

---

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What's the permission on /var/www/html/_include?

Comment: It's F13, not FC13 (I think it's like this since F7 because fedora and core repositories have merged)

Comment: It's probably the world writable permissions. Since the folder is owned by apache do `chmod a-w /var/www/html/_php_resources/cache` and `chmod o+w /var/www/html/_php_resources/cache` ... also make sure Apache does run as "apache" and not "httpd"

Comment: Output of audit2allow -a ? Or the last few lines from /var/log/audit/audit.log when this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, trying to mkdir from php. Not so much information on google but this is what I found and I guess this is the correct solution. One have to label the dir in which apache should create directories.

Label should be "httpd_sys_script_rw_t" and I found that info here: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/5/html/SELinux_FAQ/index.html#id672528

Here's how to label the dir: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t <dir>` 
Reference somewhere here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/rhlcommon-chapter-0017.html

Hope this help someone out there.